Did I incorrectly size and run my new shift cable housing?
I recently replaced the shift wire/cable housing and shift cable for my rear derailleur. One of the reasons was that the old housing was visibly worn and I could see the support wires under the outer protective plastic sheath.

I thought I had sized the new housing the same as the original housing using it as a template per Park Tool's guide. I tried to make sure it followed the same contours and length and to try and match the angle where it enters the rear derailleur.
Something's a bit off though. The previous housing seemed to be very "tight" and wouldn't move easily if I nudged it in my hand. It nestled very tightly under my rear rack's mount point and in towards the frame.

The new cable housing seems much "looser" if I nudge it with my hand near the rear derailleur, and naturally leans in the opposite direction as the previous housing. Unlike the old housing the new one wants to move away from the frame.

I've cut off the zip ties and re-run/re-installed the housing to make sure there's no slack or kinks and it seems the same after re-seating it.
I noticed that when I remove and compare the ~4 year old housing to the new ~1 month old housing, the new housing seems to already have a permanent bend in it from where it curves to enter the derailleur while the old housing seems to naturally straighten out.

I find that the Park Tool video guide for "How to Size and Install Shift Cable Housing" is a little ambiguous. In my opinion their example of "too tight" looks very similar to "just right" and similar to the documentation for my derailleur. In my opinion they look pretty similar to how the previous and new housing enter my derailleur.

I understand the Park Tools explanation may generally oversimplify some things, but then is there a better guide to sizing cable housing? The housing doesn't move when shifting at least. Shift performance seems roughly as good as with the previous housing after adjusting and re-indexing the derailleur.
I'm trying to understand if there's a better example for how to install and size the shift cable housing most appropriately. As long as things shift OK can inconsistencies like mine between old and new housing be ignored? I'm not sure if these are just cosmetic differences or indicators of incorrect length, incorrect components, or other mistakes that might bite me later on.

From photos, I can see that your cable housing runs from the derailleur all the way to the shifters, I think anyway, which makes it harder to twist the housing to have the desired effect when installed in position.   As a quick fix, you could get a cable tie and over the cable housing loop that is sticking out and loop it on the rack mount to bring it closer to the frame.

You can see in the third pic that the derailleur entry port is angled outwards. It's natural that the housing points in that direction too. The old housing was probably bent inwards (which you could replicate if you wish, but there's not much need to do so).

Since I don't see anyone saying it, there is two types of housing, compressionless and housing that compresses when under pressure.
Shifting is best cabled with compressionless housing. If it's loose and wiggly, it's probably not compressionless. The first housing you show is compressionless.

You sized the new housing correctly.
The old housing has a permanent bend.
The new housing is straight. When curved it will take a path that is different from the old one. In this case it takes a path further from the frame.
You can

Leave the new housing as it is since everything is working fine.
With your hands pre-bend the new housing to the path you desire. When you pre-bend the housing the wires in the housing will shift. The wires on the inside of the curve will stick out more at the end. You can pre-bend and then trim the housing
As MindDBike suggests, use a cable tie to encourage the housing to follow the path you desire.


Indications of too short housing:

More obvious: It restricts the movement of things. In the rear that would be the rear derailleur, in the front the handlebars (which should be able to turn all the way until they hit the frame).
Less obvious: It’s bent so tightly that it’s starting to kink which will lead to increased friction (because it pinches the cable) and a broken cable housing.

Housing which is too long isn’t great either. A question mark shape will increase friction compared to a nice simple curve. Housing friction is a lot about the capstan equation i.e. sum of all angles counts. A big question mark shape might look like it should decrease friction, but cables are quite flexible and given how stiff cable housing is you pretty much can’t make a curve which is too tight (without first kinking or otherwise damaging the housing).
From your photos the housing length towards the rear derailleur looks okay. Maybe a bit too long. If it bothers you that it bends outwards (could snag on something) you could try zip-tying it towards the chainstay.
